# Literal content ('</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I am facing the following error:

```
Literal content ('</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'
```

for the following code (inside the customer.ascx):

```
<div class="customerTableRow">
    <div class="customerTableLeftCol">
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerCountryLabel" runat="server" Text="Country:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="customerTableRightCol">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CustomerCountryDropDownList" runat="server">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CustomerCountryRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="CustomerCountryDropDownList" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move RequiredFieldValidator out of DropDownList

```
<div class="customerTableRow">
    <div class="customerTableLeftCol">
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerCountryLabel" runat="server" Text="Country:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="customerTableRightCol">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CustomerCountryDropDownList" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>


            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CustomerCountryRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="CustomerCountryDropDownList" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, later I figure out that actually I should place the RequiredFieldValidator outside the DropDownList control but I still admire how fast you post your answer. Thanks and a tick for you.